# MiniTest: how to get all elements in a fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

Instead of returning a single `User` via `users(:id)`, is there a way to get all of the users defined in `users.yml`?

In rspec this seems to be `users(:all)`, but that just looks for a user with id == `all` in Minitest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't created any additional users in your test, you can simply call the following:

```
User.all
```